# Matrix Differentiation of Least Squares Form with Hadamard Product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Suppose that $A, B, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $X = xx^{T}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$. Denote $\circ$ to be a [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) and $\| \cdot\|_{F}$ be a [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) of a matrix.

I want to find a vecotr $x$ to minimize a cost function
$$\begin{align}
J(X) & =  \left\| A - B \circ X\right\|^{2}_{F} + \lambda \left\| X \right\|^{2}_{F}.\\
&  =  \left\| A - B \circ (xx^{T})\right\|^{2}_{F} + \lambda \left\| xx^{T} \right\|^{2}_{F}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(a_{ij} - b_{ij} x_i x_j \right)^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (x_i x_j)^2.
\end{align}$$

The next step I think is to differentiate $J$ with respect to $x_i$ and $x_j$ respectively but I have no idea to proceed because what I want is the only one $x$ but here the problem becomes non-linear and I do now know how to do the differentiation on the entries of matrices. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I experienced that in most cases the [Gâteaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gâteaux_derivative) is easy to calculate.

Comment: @nam: This is just a scalar function of $x$ so you differentiate it as you differentiate as regular multivariable function. For example, when $n = 2$, you have $J(x) = (a_{11} - b_{11} x_1^2)^2 + (a_{12} - b_{12} x_1 x_2)^2 + (a_{21} - b_{21} x_2 x_1)^2 + (a_{22} - b_{22} x_2^2)^2 + \lambda (x_1^4 + 2 x_1^2 x_2^2 + x_2^4)$.

Comment: @nam, I would recommend you to edit the question title - Matrix Differentiation of Least Squares Form with Hadamard Product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective function is a function of $ x $ hence the gradient is a function of the vector.

By separating the functions:

$$ J \left( x \right) = f \left( x \right) + \lambda g \left( x \right) $$

Then:

$$ \nabla f \left( x \right)_{k} = \sum_{i = k, j} -2 {b}_{ij} {x}_{j} \left( {a}_{ij} - {b}_{ij} {x}_{i} {x}_{j} \right) + \sum_{i, j = k} -2 {b}_{ij} {x}_{j} \left( {a}_{ij} - {b}_{ij} {x}_{i} {x}_{j} \right) $$

And

$$ \nabla g \left( x \right)_{k} = \sum_{i = k, j} 2 {x}_{j} \left( 
{x}_{i} {x}_{j} \right) + \sum_{i, j = k} 2 {x}_{i} \left( 
{x}_{i} {x}_{j} \right) $$

In total:

$$ \nabla J \left( x \right)_{k} = \nabla f \left( x \right)_{k} + \lambda \nabla g \left( x \right)_{k} $$

I'm pretty sure you can extract a structure in the solution in order to vectorize the gradient calculation.

You can find numerical validation in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q2411200 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2410741).

#### Update

I also used Gradient Descent to optimize the problem.
Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate so much for your code and I accept that the gradient of $J$ is of the form $\nabla J \left( x \right)_{k} = \nabla f \left( x \right)_{k} + \lambda \nabla g \left( x \right)_{k}$. However, what I want is to set $\nabla J = 0$ and find the $x$ to minimize the original cost function $J$. I have tried $n=2$ case but it is subject to multiple solutions because it involved $x^3$ terms. May I know if you have good idea to find the minimizer $x$? Thanks again.

Comment: I can try write something. The question is, what's the model?

Comment: In my application, I was given matrices $A$ and $B$ and try to find a $X = x x^{T}$ to fit $A = B \circ X$ and I add a regularized term to control $X$. That is why I formulated the cost function in my question. I can clarify my model if I remain unclear. By the way, I would appreciate you if you can write how to derive $\nabla f(x)$ and $\nabla g(x)$ in more details. It sounds like you have made use of chain rule but I am interested how you can write the summation sign with indices $i, j, k$ compactly. It is amazing and I think it can beneficial to others with similar scenarios. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a code to implement that. I'm not sure about structure. People more experience than me with Frobebnius Norm and the Hadamard Product will chime in hopefully.

Comment: @nam, I added solver to the code. Regarding convexity, I think your problem in relate to $ X $ is convex. So it might be better solve it in 2 steps.

Comment: I appreciate for your help and I think the code basically solved my problem in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @nam, You're welcome. By the way, have you analyzed the Convexity of your problem?

Comment: Yes, I am still checking with simple cases and will reply here if I have result about it.